# Won't Read in My Image

Tags: c, io, scanf, printf, ppm

I am reading in a PPM file, and I have used printf's throughout the function to see if it will print but for some reason it prints the p3/comment/width/height/maxcolor but it wont print the pixels... I tried checking via using printf statements inside and outside my nested for loops but it wont read in the data...Any ideas??

```
void ReadImages(struct ImageType *imgur, struct ImageType *imgur2)
   {
     int i=0, j=0;
     char filename[30];
     char filename2[30];

     FILE *inputfile;
     fprintf(stdout, "Please enter the filename/location of the first image\n");
     fscanf(stdin, "%s", filename);
     inputfile = fopen(filename, "r");

     fscanf(inputfile,"%[^\n]%c", imgur->ppImage, &imgur->newlinechar);
     fscanf(inputfile,"%[^\n]%c", imgur->comment, &imgur->newlinechar);
     fscanf(inputfile, "%i %i", &imgur->width, &imgur-height);
     fscanf(inputfile, "%i", &imgur->maxColor);

     for(i=imgur->height-1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
           for(j=0; j > imgur->width; j++)
              {
                 fscanf(inputfile, "%i", &imgur->image[i][j].red);
                 fscanf(inputfile,"%i", &imgur->image[i][j].green);
                 fscanf(inputfile,"%i", &imgur->image[i][j].blue);
               }
        }
```

Yes I have made sure that my struct is int red/green/blue and I have checked on printing out the comment/maxcolor/and everything else that all works.

Comment: `for(j=0; j > imgur->width; j++)` - That condition is wrong. `j` will never be greater than the image width.

Comment: @EdS. And that was it..... I should have caught that.. I knew it was my for loop but I thought i was reading in the width one less than j when I was doing the exact opposite... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you allocated storage for your image at `imgur->image`?  If not, then your program is crashing at that point.

Also, you do realize there's no print statements in your `for` loop that reads the pixels, so that could also be why it's not printing out the pixels.

**Edit:**  Aha, this is likely it:

```
       for(j=0; j > imgur->width; j++)
```

Your comparison is backward.  You want:

```
       for(j=0; j < imgur->width; j++)
```

Comment: I removed it, I have a function taht prints later, this is a function to read in the two files, then a function to flip one of the files, then a function to blend them and a final function to output them. I commented out the out put and was using printfs to see where my data for the pixels were lost. I did have a printf within it but it wasn't printing out for some odd reason

Comment: Also I have two structs, one that is pixel image[450][450] which is allocated storage.

Comment: @user3078582 : See my edit regarding your loop condition in the `j` loop.